# How to create group on Facebook using Facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to create groups on facebook using Facebook Graph api. After referring this site http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/app-game-groups/#impl where they have mentioned on how to create groups, i have written following code. But it is not working.can u plz help me on how to create groups on facebook

**code:-**

Ext.Ajax.request ({
                             url : 'https://graph.facebook.com/342283535872845/groups/description?access_token=342283535872845|9Adi1Gb9qf2UpcZHu_NywK5bBxI',
                             dataType: 'json',
                             timeout: 60000,
                             type:'POST',
                             success: this.Success,
                             failure: this.Failure,
                             scope: this
                             });
           },

**Response :-**

{
   "data": [

]
}

The response should have group id but instead i am getting null data.
Please help me with this on how to create groups?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be the admin of the application and you must have the app access token.

Here is the sample code

$app_token = $app_id."|".$app_secret ; This is how you can gain the app access token
$response =  $facebook->api(
            "/APPID/groups",  "POST",array (
             'access_token' => $app_token,'name' => 'TEST NAME', 
  )
);